# How to convert a string to a number where number is embed in further string

Tags: python

hi I have a string like this

```
a = "'0123','0124'"
```

**and I am trying to convert it into something like this  b = (0123,0124)**

and doing something like this

```
b = int(a.replace(',', ''))
```

and getting error

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:**

Comment: `int` works on a single string to produce a single integer.

Comment: Try: `b = tuple(int(i[1:-1]) for i in a.split(','))`

Comment: @Corralien: OP asked for the leading zeros, although I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: What do you mean by `0123`? Is it equal to `123`?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
b = tuple(int(i[1:-1]) for i in a.split(','))
print(b)

# Output
(123, 124)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes, split the string at comma, and use `int()` to convert each of them to an integer.

```
b = [int(x) for x in a.replace("'", "").split(',')]
```

Leading zeroes don't make any sense in this result. They're part of a printed representation of a number, not the numeric value itself. You can add them when displaying the numbers later.

Comment: OP asked for the leading zeros, although I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

output = [int(i) for i in literal_eval("'0123','0124'")]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `a.replace(',', '')` will only replace the `,` in the middle with an empty string, making it `"'0123''0124'"`, now this still has the quotes to be handled of, that's why it raised the error.

You can split the string with the comma, and replace the single quotes with empty string and pass that to `int()`, like this...

```py
a = "'0123','0124'"
b = tuple([int(i.replace("'", "")) for i in a.split(",")])

print(b)
```